# PHP array unexpected output

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

if (!$con) {die('Could not connect to databse' . mysqli_error($con));}

mysqli_select_db($con, 'timetable');
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf-8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE date = '2019-3-21'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$b=array();

for($i = 8; $i<=20; $i+=2){

   if($row[$i.':00'] == 1){
       array_push($b, 1);}

   else{
    array_push($b, 0);}

echo json_encode($b);
}
?>
```

I am expecting to get echo like [1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
but the output is actually 7 arrays like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61vPs.png)[1,1][1,1,0][1,1,0,0][1,1,0,0,0][1,1,0,0,0,1][1,1,0,0,0,1,0].
I don't know what's wrong is the code.
The database is simple as in the image. Thx
[database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61vPs.png)

Comment: Move your echo statement outside of your `for` loop

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo since it is such a small mistake and of no use to future visitors

Answer (score -1):

your loop is printing the array multiple times, if you want to print the array only once at the end of the loop, you should do

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

if (!$con) {die('Could not connect to databse' . mysqli_error($con));}

mysqli_select_db($con, 'timetable');
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf-8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE date = '2019-3-21'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$b=array();

for($i = 8; $i<=20; $i+=2){

   if($row[$i.':00'] == 1){
       array_push($b, 1);}

   else{
    array_push($b, 0);}

}

echo json_encode($b);
?>
```

Comment: When the answer is "move one line of code", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232).